# js добавление элемента option при условии

Tags: javascript

сделал добавление при клике на select второго option, при условии что первый option равен тексту.
Он работает но при нажатии на другой селект, он удаляет второй option у другого селекта. Помогите понять почему так происходит.

```js
let newOption = new Option("Не выполнено");
let newOpt = new Option("Выполнено")
let sel = document.querySelectorAll('.select');
for (let s = 0; s < sel.length; s++) {
    sel[s].addEventListener('click', function () {
        let opt = sel[s].querySelectorAll('.option');
        for (let a = 0; a < opt.length; a++)
            if (opt[a].text == 'Выполнено') {
                sel[s].append(newOption)
            } else {
                sel[s].append(newOpt)
            }
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Таблица принтеры</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <section>
   <select class="select">
   <option class ="option">Не выполнено</option>
   </select>
             <select class="select">
   <option class ="option">Не выполнено</option>
   </select>
   

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128205/discussion-on-question-by-savage-js---option--).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sel = document.querySelectorAll('.select');
for (let s = 0; s < sel.length; s++) {
    let newOption = new Option("Не выполнено");
    let newOpt = new Option("Выполнено")
    sel[s].addEventListener('click', function () {
        let opt = sel[s].querySelectorAll('.option');
        for (let a = 0; a < opt.length; a++) {
            if (opt[a].text == 'Выполнено') {
                sel[s].append(newOption)
            } else {
                sel[s].append(newOpt)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Таблица принтеры</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <section>
   <select class="select">
   <option class ="option">Не выполнено</option>
   </select>
             <select class="select">
   <option class ="option">Не выполнено</option>
   </select>
   

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавь описание что именно делал, сейчас тяжело заметить чем код в ответе отличается от кода в вопросе